# Problems with generating another "Joke" Statement

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, netbeans

Currently, I am creating a simple program that tells jokes to users.

> Bot: How can you get four suits for a dollar? Type reveal to view answer
>   You: reveal
>   Bot: Buy a deck of cards. *giggle giggle*
>   Bot: Do you wish to continue? Yes or no?
>   You: Yes
>   Bot: What do you call a boomerang that won't come back? Type reveal to view answer

That was my intended script. However, I faced a problem:

> Bot: Do you wish to continue? Yes or no?
>   You: Yes
>   Bot: Wrong >:D

The bot print out "Wrong" instead of generating another joke. Here is my code:

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomNumber;
        String userInput;

        String[] jokesAnswer = {"Snowballs! HAHA ", "A stick!!! :D", "A pork chop.", "A piano! HEHE ", "A dead centipede!! xD", "At the crystal ball. *chuckle chuckle*",
            "A conversation. TEEHEE", "Buy a deck of cards. *giggle giggle*"};
        String[] jokes = {"What is the difference between a snowman and a snowwoman?", "What do you call a boomerang that won't come back?",
            "What do you call a pig that does karate?", "What has a lot of keys but can not open any doors?", "What lies on its back, one hundred feet in the air?",
            "Where do fortune tellers dance?", "What can you hold without ever touching it?", "How can you get four suits for a dollar?"};

        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * jokes.length);
        System.out.println("Bot: " + jokes[randomNumber] + " Type reveal to view answer");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("You: ");
            userInput = input.nextLine();
            userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
            if (userInput.equals("reveal")) {
                System.out.println("Bot: " + jokesAnswer[randomNumber] + "\nBot: Do you want to hear another joke? :D Yes or No?");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Bot: Wrong! >:D");
            }
        } while (!userInput.equals("no"));

    }
```

Comment: Your logic has gotten slightly mixed up. userInput is assigned only while inside the do loop and outputting there. So even if no is typed it will always "Wrong" first.

Comment: Step through your code by hand. You'll get the same result. A useful and common structure is `x = someMethod(); while(x != y) { process(x); x = someMethod(); }`

Comment: Debug through your code and you will realize what went wrong.

Comment: In simple code flows like this most of the logical error can be found by simple dry run of the code logic. Like here, when `userInput` is `no`, which is not `reveal` therefore wrong output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a little bit broken. You need to tell the joke within the do-while loop, else you'll only ever tell it once. You need to be able to handle the situation where they repeatedly type something other than 'reveal', so I added another loop for that case. It's a while-loop as opposed to a do-while because it does not need to be guaranteed to happen at all.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * jokes.length);
    System.out.println("Bot: " + jokes[randomNumber] + " Type reveal to view answer");

    System.out.print("You: ");
    userInput = input.nextLine();
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

    while (!userInput.equals("reveal"))
    {
        System.out.println("Bot: Wrong! >:D");

        System.out.print("You: ");
        userInput = input.nextLine();
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
    }

    System.out.println("Bot: " + jokesAnswer[randomNumber] + "\nBot: Do you want to hear another joke? :D Yes or No?");

    System.out.print("You: ");
    userInput = input.nextLine();
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

} while (!userInput.equals("no"));
```

I would also move the user input statements to their own function to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of your code failure is that your logic is not cevring all the possible scenarios with the user input: you are on a while loop until this fails

```
(!userInput.equals("no"));
```

but inside the loop you have this

```
if (userInput.equals("reveal")) {
       System.out.println(
                    "Bot: " + jokesAnswer[randomNumber] + "\nBot: Do you want to hear another joke? :D Yes or No?");
 } else {
            System.out.println("Bot: Wrong! >:D");
 }
```

so basically anything that is not "reveal" will bring you to the same point...

solution:

you could expand the options

```
else if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
       System.out.println("yes it is");
} else {
       System.out.println("Bot: Wrong! >:D");
}
```

Comment: You may also want to use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of just `equals`

Comment: @4castle my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually prompt the user for further input inside the loop, so there's no way for the user to actually respond to the question, nor is there a mechanism for it to actually tell further jokes. All of that logic is completely outside the loop, so it won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Do-While-Loop` isn´t correct, I´d suggest you something like the following:

Note that the bot waits for you to write "reveal" and can´t go on without it, but I´m sure you see the point and can alter the code as you need it. (if not feel free to ask)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int randomNumber;
    String userInput;

    String[] jokesAnswer = {"Snowballs! HAHA ", "A stick!!! :D", "A pork chop.", "A piano! HEHE ", "A dead centipede!! xD", "At the crystal ball. *chuckle chuckle*",
            "A conversation. TEEHEE", "Buy a deck of cards. *giggle giggle*"};
    String[] jokes = {"What is the difference between a snowman and a snowwoman?", "What do you call a boomerang that won't come back?",
            "What do you call a pig that does karate?", "What has a lot of keys but can not open any doors?", "What lies on its back, one hundred feet in the air?",
            "Where do fortune tellers dance?", "What can you hold without ever touching it?", "How can you get four suits for a dollar?"};

    do{
        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * jokes.length);
        System.out.println("Bot: " + jokes[randomNumber] + " Type reveal to view answer");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);            

        do{            
            userInput = input.nextLine();
            userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

            if (userInput.equals("reveal")) {
                System.out.println("Bot: " + jokesAnswer[randomNumber] + "\nBot: Do you want to hear another joke? :D Yes or No?");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Bot: Wrong! >:D");
            }
        }while(!userInput.equals("reveal"))

        userInput = input.nextLine();
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
    }while(!userInput.equals("no"))
}
```

If you want to not reaveal the joke when the `userInput != "reveal"` and just want to ask if to continue you can replace the inner `do-while-loop` with the following:

```
userInput = input.nextLine();
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

if (userInput.equals("reveal")) {
    System.out.println("Bot: " + jokesAnswer[randomNumber]);
} else {
    System.out.println("Bot: Wrong! >:D");
}

System.out.println("Bot: Do you want to hear another joke? :D Yes or No?");
```

In this case, no matter if the bot reveals the joke, or says "wrong" it will ask you if to continue or not.

Comment: Oh ok, im not fimiliar with the scanner, but I´m going to edit the answer.

Comment: So you did. Okay, I'm deleting my comments.